# Using local storage in angular to store which checkboxes were checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have a list that can be sorted through checkboxes. I wrote up a little script that should store the check values so on refresh the filtered list shows the same items, as they did before leaving the page.

Currently when I refresh it checks all of my checkboxes, not just the one I checked.

Here is how my inputs are set up:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filters" ng-click="includeBrand('Brand A')" />Brand A
```

and here is my function that should keep the same ones checked:

```
$(function () {
    var data = localStorage.getItem("filter-by");

    if (data !== null) {
        $("input[name='filters']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }


});



$("input[name='filters']").click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        localStorage.setItem("filter-by", $(this).val());
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("filters");
    }

});
```

What could be going wrong as to make it check "all of the above"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated response**

There's a couple of things going on in your codepen. Here's my recommendations:

First, add a data- attribute, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filters" data-filter-by="Brand A" ng-click="includeBrand('Brand A')" />Brand A
```

Update your click-handler to be more like this:

```
$("input[name='filters']").click(function () {
  var items = localStorage.getItem("filter-by");
  items = items ? JSON.parse(items) : [];

 var data = $(this).data('filter-by');
 var index = items.indexOf(data);

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    items.push(data);
  } else if (index >= 0) {
    items.splice(index, 1);
  }

  localStorage.setItem("filter-by", JSON.stringify(items));
});
```

And lastly, update the code where you pre-select checkboxes to be something more like this:

```
$(function () {
  var items = localStorage.getItem("filter-by");
  items = items ? JSON.parse(items) : [];

  $("input[name='filters']").each(function(index, input) {
    var data = $(input).data('filter-by');
    if (items.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
      $(input).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  });
});
```

Does this make sense?

**Original response**

This line...

```
$("input[name='filters']").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Checks all inputs named "filters" - not just individual ones. I suspect what you *mean* to do is iterate over your filter checkboxes and only select those where the `val()` value matches the item stored in localstorage. So something like this...

```
$("input[name='filters']").each(function(index, input) {
  if ($(input).val() === data) {
    $(input).attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

I should also point out that you're writing to `filter-by` in one place and removing `filters` in 2 lines below. Those should be the same key.

Comment: Should I be looking at something along the lines of
`$("input[name='filters']").val("checked", "checked");`

Apologies, this is still my first endeavor with angular/local storage

Comment: Not sure what you were asking with this follow up, but I updated my response to show an example of what I meant in case it was unclear...

Comment: I inputed your line, and it 'inversed' my code? Now when I click to filter by brand a, it shows all brands b-z, and hides a?

Comment: inverted? I'm not sure what you're saying. Show a Plunker or something.

Comment: Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/RNyYmz?editors=001) If you look at it, when you click "Brand A" in the 'brands' drop down, it will hide the 'brand a' block.

Comment: I understand now. Give me a few and I'll update my suggestion.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help man, sorry I couldn't really explain it by typing lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73441/discussion-between-brianvaughn-and-user4470749).